# retrieve category for specific vimeo video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I believe that a vimeo video is added to a category - determined by vimeo through some intelligent algorithm.  The vimeo.videos.getInfo method does not seem to provide the category.  Is it possible, through an api call, to retrieve that category to which a specific vimeo video has been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/categories/[id]/videos/[id] is a pattern that the Vimeo API often uses for checking whether something exists in something else. Unfortunately it is not currently supported in the API.

I'll make a note to add it in the future.